# Stanford Classifier producing wrong results

Tags: java, machine-learning, stanford-nlp, text-classification

I'm trying to perform a basic text classification with the [Stanford Classifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier). My example data set is based on [Ham or Spam](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigmlcom/python/master/data/spam.csv).

This is my code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
ColumnDataClassifier cdc = new ColumnDataClassifier(props);

Classifier<String, String> cl = cdc.makeClassifier(cdc.readTrainingExamples("data.train"));

for (String line : ObjectBank.getLineIterator("data.test", "utf-8")) {
    Datum<String, String> d = cdc.makeDatumFromLine(line);
    System.out.println(line + "  ==>  " + cl.classOf(d));
}
```

However, whatever text I try to classify, it always classifies it as Ham. The following sentence is clearly Spam, still it is classified as Ham:

> FREE MESSAGE Activate your 500 FREE Text Messages by replying to this message with the word FREE For terms & conditions, visit [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The fact that that there are a few errors is not surprising, but there's a more serious issue since it predicts every instance with the majority label. First you could check that the training data is correctly interpreted, i.e. every instance has the label it's supposed to have after `readTrainingExamples`. My guess is that something goes wrong there, maybe the format is not what the function expects. Also there's the question of the size of the training set: if it's too small, the classifier would probably default to the majority class all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was that I didn't provide any properties:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
ColumnDataClassifier cdc = new ColumnDataClassifier(props);
```

You can either specify the properties directly in the code:

```
// set up pipeline properties
Properties props = new Properties();
// set the list of annotators to run
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote");
// set a property for an annotator, in this case the coref annotator is being set to use the neural algorithm
props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
```

Or you can provide a properties file:

```
ColumnDataClassifier cdc = new ColumnDataClassifier(propFile);
```